# On double tap image zoom and dragscroll within div using jquery

Tags: jquery, touch

I want to on double tap on an image the image will be zoom and dragscroll the image within div.

for doubletap I use this jquery. But, it's not working like I'd expect.

```
if (touchtime == 0) {
                            touchtime = new Date().getTime();
                        } else {
                            if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtime) < 800) {

                                if(jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').hasClass('transition')){
                                    if(srsize <= 640 ){
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').attr('id','popup_img_content');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').parent().removeClass('dragscroll');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('div.rg-image').css('overflow-x','');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('div.rg-image').css('overflow-y','');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').removeClass('transition');
                                        if(jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_prev').hasClass('hidenavigation')) {
                                            jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_prev').removeClass('hidenavigation');
                                        } if(jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_next').hasClass('hidenavigation')) {
                                            jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_next').removeClass('hidenavigation');
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    if(srsize <= 640 ){
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').attr('id','popup_img_content');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').parent().addClass('dragscroll');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('div.rg-image').css('overflow-x','scroll');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('div.rg-image').css('overflow-y','scroll');
                                        jQuery('div.popup').find('img.ept-custom-img').addClass('transition');
                                        if(jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_prev').css('display') == "block") {
                                            jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_prev').addClass('hidenavigation');
                                        } if(jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_next').css('display') == "block") {
                                            jQuery('div.popup').find('#main_image_next').addClass('hidenavigation');
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                touchtime = 0;
                            } else {
                                touchtime = new Date().getTime();
                            }
                        }
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What is not working? and how?

Comment: Double is not proper working. First I click one time, then after 60 seconds I click. So, it's consider as double tap. Which is not feasible. And dragscroll is not working after image zoom.

Comment: Can you please me provide fiddle or codepen of this example?